# PlantUML: How can I relate "grouping components" (package, node, folder, frame, cloud or database) with another grouping component?

Tags: uml, plantuml

- I'm using PlantUML
- I'm using packages to group components.
- I'm looking to relate a package with another package. In the picture above "Services Layer" with "Interface Layer"
- The only way I can actually relate them is component to component.

[image: two packages here that I would like to relate]

Comment: The only legal (IIRC) connectors would be nesting and dependency. Which are you trying to create (not that I know PlantUML, but generally...).

Comment: @qwerty_so Dependency between packages.

Comment: Google spits out quite a number of results on a search _plantuml package dependency_ like https://forum.plantuml.net/8975/dependency-between-packages-containing-classes (no idea if that one helps)